# Дизайн приложнения Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как сделать такие контейнеры. Они как бы на поверхности и сзади серый фон и кажеться есть тень. Ну думаю вы поймете посмотрев на [image: фото]

Comment: Делаеться это через shape-ы,
Вот статья которая описывает как их делать:
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/shape.php

Comment: Посмотрите еще CardView(а если интересует еще и функционал, как реализовать, то посмотрите еще RecyclerView), в нем можно создать. Найдете очень много статей.
Может пригодится либа  для recyclerView: https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: @Tvester я понял что такое shape и что он может но не понял как сделать прямь такой эффект

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский Cardview минимальный Api 21 у меня же 19 а с RecyclerView  пользоваться умею

Comment: добавьте библиотеку `com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1` и пользуйтесь `CardView` с API 7+

Comment: Это обычный CardView в котором серый background. Тень у cardView накладывается без проблем. В общем тут не вижу ничего необычного. Просто хорошо скомпановано

Comment: @Романыч я не знал что это называеться CardView просто

Comment: Тут реализация cardView  + recyclerView. В принципе это основа наверное 90% приложений. Просто тут реализация более сложная и навороченная. Много вложений итд.

Comment: @Романыч RecyclerView можно дать орентацию вертикально и горизонтально. Что нужно сделать чтобы она так в сеточку?

Comment: Для сеточки есть GridLayoutManager

Comment: @Романыч Понял спасибо

Comment: @Романыч нужна опять ваша помощь. Прописал GridLayoutManager но все равно идут Linear. Может что то еще нужно прописать?

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под "идут linear" менеджеру вы передаете параметры, одним из параметров там контекст второй количество столбцов в сетке например 2 или3 или1 или , может быть 10))  что бы помочь более детально надо видеть код.

Comment: @Романыч разобрался. Я не знал что нужно менеджер вводить программно. Еще вопрос в отдельном xml храниться CardView вью которого передаеться RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Так вот размеры какие ставите? Фиксированые?

Comment: Вообще все зависит от нужды. Размеры cardView обычно match parent и wrap content. Надо понимать что если задавать размеры явно, то будут проблемы с отображением на некоторых ( возможно на очень многих) устройствах.

Comment: @Романыч понятно спасибо за совет